# CDI @Inject or plain old java ee 5 annotations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, cdi, inject

Let's say I have stateless EJB as below:

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

So this is injection with java ee 5 annotations e.g. @PersistenceContext.
If I use CDI I can't simply use `@Inject`, right? I need to create producer for this an use qualifier as below

```
class DBProducer {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence")
    @MyDatabase
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

I don't mind the LOC amount. My question is what way should I use? Is it ok to mix those two: CDI `@Inject` and those old Java EE 5 annotations like `@EJB`, `@PersistenceContext` etc, or is it better to stick to CDI and use it everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could do either one. The difference is pretty minor for most people (do I get a proxy or the actual object?).

Answer (score 0):

Not everything can be injected with '@Inject' yet.

Eventually everything should move to that, but it may be Java EE 9 or even 10 before that happens I'm afraid.

Having @Inject everywhere should make it more straightforward for alternatives and extensions to be configured.